# How to link /usr/local to user specific directory?

Tags: macos, homebrew, filesystem, mount

Is it possible to map the `/usr/local/` path on MacOS to a directory that is unique for each user, for example `~/local/`? Or is there another way to solve the following:

I trying to give each user on my MacOS server a personal homebrew installation. However the disadvantage of installing homebrew in a non-standard user directory is that all packages will need to be rebuilt from source. Homebrew only uses the binary bottles for the default `/usr/local` dir.

Preferably I would like each user to have a copy of homebrew in their home dir, and somehow map the `/usr/local` path to that directory so that the binaries still work.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  Why would you want to have user specific homebrew installations?

Comment: Because users need to be free to configure and manage their own software without interfering with each other?

Comment: Do you have multiple developers all working on a single machine?

Comment: Yes. It's a compute/build server with many users, each with their own requirements.

Comment: I've seen multiple people use the *same* homebrew install, but never multiple people using multiple instances of homebrew sandboxed for individual needs..  They need their own machines.

Comment: You could use Macports as it is designed like all Unix to have one install shared between users - in this case the install would be the union of what is needed to be installed - config files will be in the home directories

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it - but it is relatively involved.

Essentially you could chroot each user into his own directory and replicate the filesystem in there, except for the /usr/local directory, which would then be user-specific.

To access the system directories inside the chroot, you could use bindfs, osxfs or even a NFS mount.

Far easier to just let each user have a non-default homebrew and let them rebuild all their packages as needed. By definition, not sharing one folder implies duplicate storage and work but that’s likely far less hassle to set up.